# ¿como hago que mis cajas de productos sean grandes y se coloquen en fila?

Tags: html, css

> > tengo el siguiente codigo de html que representa una pagina web de una tienda online y coloque distintas cajas en el. trate de organizarlo lo mejor posible pero aun me esta dando algunos problemas.

```
<div class="C_tarjetahorizontal">
    <div class="card">
        </div>
        <figure>
            <img src="images/teclado.jpg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
            <div class="contenido">
                <span>
                    Producto <br>
                    Review del Producto
                    <br>
                </span>
                <a href="#"> comprar</a>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Container_tarjeta">
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/audifonos.jpg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto <br>
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/grafica.jpg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/microfono.jpg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/teclado2.jpeg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto <br>
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/laptop1.jpeg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto <br>
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/laptop2.jpeg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto <br>
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/laptop3.jpeg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto <br>
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

y este codigo de css que se aplica a las tarjetas (el de la tarjeta horizontal, es una caja que va por encima de las cajas pequeñas).

```
.Container_tarjeta{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.card{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 400ms ease-out;
    cursor: default;
}
.C_tarjetahorizontal{
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: contain;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 400ms ease-out;
    cursor: default;
}
```

> > > no se como hacer que las cajas de los productos (las cajas pequeñas) sean mas grandes y se ajusten como una fila.
> > > quiero que los productos tengan una organizacion parecida a las de tiendas online
> > > pero cada vez que agrego una caja con un producto, todas se hacen mas pequeñas.

Comment: Te recomendaria que pegases un codepen con el código así no te podemos ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Principalmente te falta el `flex-wrap: wrap;` para que las "cajas" bajen a la siguiente fila cuando no quepa en la fila.

Pero además

- Tienes un div mal cerrado en la 3ra linea de tu código
- Yo sacaría el `max-width: 1000px;` y agregaría un `max-width: 1000px;`
- Sacaría el `margin:20px` y lo cambio por `gap:20px`
- En la clase `.card` cambiaría el `width: 50%;` por algo como `width: clamp(200px, 24%, 100%);` donde el 200px sería el mínimo, 24% el valor (mientras se cumpla el max y el min) y 100% el máximo.

```css
.Container_tarjeta{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
     gap:20px;
}
.card{
    width: clamp(200px, 24%, 100%);
   
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 400ms ease-out;
    cursor: default;
}
.C_tarjetahorizontal{
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: contain;
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 400ms ease-out;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container_tarjeta">
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/audifonos.jpg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto <br>
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/grafica.jpg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/microfono.jpg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/teclado2.jpeg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto <br>
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/laptop1.jpeg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto <br>
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/laptop2.jpeg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto <br>
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/laptop3.jpeg" width="100%" alt="teclado">
        </figure>
        <div class="contenido">
            Producto
            <p>
                Review del producto <br>
            </p>
            <a href="#">comprar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactamente no sé a qué te refieres con que se ajusten como una fila. La solución que te doy hace que las cajas pequeñas se organicen en varias filas según el tamaño de la ventana. Te dejo el código CSS que he modificado y te explico por qué lo he hecho.

```
.Container_tarjeta {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }

    .card {
        width: 200px;
        margin: 20px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        transition: all 400ms ease-out;
        cursor: default;
    }

    .card.little{
        height: 150px;
    }
```

Empiezo de arriba hacia abajo. En **.Container_tarjeta** he especificado que el contenedor NO contenga la fila, sino que la **vaya "rompiendo" en función del tamaño del contenedor** (que eso sucede cuando es menor a 1000px).

En la clase **.card** he especificado que la propiedad **width tenga un tamaño fijo para evitar que la tarjeta se redimensione** con la ventana del dispositivo al usar porcentaje.

Y por último, podrás ver que **he añadido una clase .little** a las tarjetas de productos **para asignarles un alto fijo** y así no afecte a la tarjeta horizontal superior.

Espero que te haya podido ayudar.